# File included with <> can't find a file included with ""

Tags: c++, include, include-path

I'm developing a library that is to be used (after compiled and installed) by another developer. All my includes are like this:

```
#include "../exception/CException.h"
```

All goes well but when I install the library and use it in another program with #include <> that include a file that have #include "../exception/CException.h" the last file is not found. Why?

Any help to improve include usage?

Comment: `""` is relative to the file, `<>` is relative to the include directory of the compiler

Comment: hi, thank this is right, but scons don't see the file included in this way

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That is wrong. How the search works is implementation defined. In many implementations, you can specify a set of directories to search within. Note that in any implementation, if the search for "foo.h" fails the preprocessor must try to interpret the #include directive as <foo.h>.

Comment: in scons i have resolved calling this method this env.Append(CPPPATH='.') to the Enveronment() class

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a relative path is that we don't know for sure what it is relative to. Different compilers have different ways of doing this.

You should rather use

```
#include "yourlib/exception/CException.h"
```

similar to Boost.

If you install this as a subdirectory `yourlib` in `/usr/local` the  compiler should be able to find that.

Comment: thanks for correction:-) in Xcode i setup also the local directory as search path and now #include "yourlib/exception/CException.h" syntax work but i need to use #include <yourlib/exception/CException.h> i this that using <> is more portable. The only problem is now with scons

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to distribute `../exception/CException.h` with your library. If it's really part of your library putting it in a subdirectory rather than a sibling would be preferable.

Comment: i have seen the boost use directly the syntax: #include <boost/...> in file that need to access other include. i need install my include file into /usr/local and after install other people need to use my include